# @query elasticsearch spring data to get max id

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to get max and min id by @query elasticsearch spring data ,so I use the following code but I get theis error
No query registered for [aggs]];

```
@Query(value="{\"aggs\":{\"max_id\":{\"max\":{\"field\":\"id\"}}}}")
Segment findMaxId();
```

stack trace

```
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to
execute phase [dfs], all shards failed; shardFailures  
{[QvVc1wxqRoWtkUhGSDULCg][segment][0]: SearchParseException[[segment][0]:
from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source
[{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":
     "eyJhZ2dzIjp7Im1heF9pZCI6eyJtYXgiOnsiZmllb
GQiOiJpZCJ9fX19"}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[segment] No query
registered for [aggs]]; }{[QvVc1wxqRoWtkUhGSDULCg][segment][1]:
SearchParseException[[segment][1]: from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure 
[Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query_binary":
"eyJhZ2dzIjp7Im1heF9pZCI6eyJtYXgiOnsiZmllbGQiOiJpZCJ9fX19"}]]]; nested:
QueryParsingException[[segment] No query registered for [aggs]];
 }{[QvVc1wxqRoWtkUhGSDULCg][segment][2]:
 SearchParseException[[segment][2]: from[0],size[10]: Parse Failure 
   [Failed to parse source
```

Comment: It is not possible to use `aggs` inside the `@Query` annotation, which is meant only for queries.

Comment: So How can I get max?

Comment: Note that you should have updated [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656770/use-query-elasticsearch-spring-data-to-get-min-and-max) instead of creating a new one for the same topic..

Comment: I used @Query(value="{\"sort\": { \"id\" : {\"order\" : \"desc\"}},\"bool\" : {\"match_all\" : {}}}") but get  No query registered for [sort]]

Comment: I deleted the other question